# Change of basis in linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

The sets $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{D}$  shown below are bases for $\mathscr{P}_2$ and $M_2(R)$ respectively.

$\mathcal{B}=\{\mathbf{b_1}=1+3x+x^2,\,\mathbf{b_2}=2+5x+2x^2,\,\mathbf{b_3}=3+3x+4x^2\}$

$\mathcal{D}=\left\{ \mathbf{d_1}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 0 &
  0 \end{bmatrix},\, \mathbf{d_2}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 
 \end{bmatrix},\, \mathbf{d_3}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 
 \end{bmatrix},\, \mathbf{d_4}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 
 \end{bmatrix}\,\right\}.$

If the basis $\mathcal{S}=\{1,x,x^2\}$, then

$P_{\mathcal{S\leftarrow B}}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2&3 \\ 3 &
  5&3\\1 &2&4 \end{bmatrix}$

If $T: \mathscr{P}_2 \rightarrow M_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ is the linear transformation that satisfies

$T(\mathbf{b_1})=\mathbf{d_1}-\mathbf{d_4}$

$T(\mathbf{b_2})=\mathbf{d_2}+\mathbf{d_3}$

$T(\mathbf{b_3})=\mathbf{d_3}-\mathbf{d_1}$

Then $[T]_{\mathcal{D\leftarrow B}}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0&-1 \\ 0 &
  1&0\\0 &1&1\\-1&0&0 \end{bmatrix}$

Can anyone teach me how to find $[T]_{\mathcal{D\leftarrow B}}$?

Comment: Look at the columns and compare with the coefficients of $\textbf{d}$.

Answer (score 1):

Just observe that
$$ 
\begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{d}_1 - \mathbf{d}_4 \\ \mathbf{d}_2 + \mathbf{d}_3\\ \mathbf{d}_3 - \mathbf{d}_1\\ \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0&-1 \\ 0 &
  1&0\\0 &1&1\\-1&0&0 \end{pmatrix}^\top
\begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{d}_1 \\ \mathbf{d}_2\\\mathbf{d}_3\\\mathbf{d}_4 \end{pmatrix}$$
where $^\top$ denotes the transposition of the matrix.